# How can I add tabindex="0" to all h2s and h3s items within an ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wai-aria

HI I am using jquery ui with an accordion that has a nested accordion within one of it's tabs.The first tab is getting tabindex="0", dynamcially through jquery. All of The following tabs gets tabindex="-1". The tabindex is being applied to the h2 and h3s. I'd like all the h2 items which are the tabs to have the tabindex=0 value and not tabindex="-1" as it is not focusable.

How can I do this with jquery?
thanks

Comment: `$('ul li').attr('tabindex', 0)`

Comment: anycode of your jquery not behaving as you wish it did ?

Comment: Alon - how can I apply it to the h2 and h3s? They are currently getting index="-1" and I need to over ride it with index=0? thx I tried hard coding tabindex=0 it but no luck. thx

Comment: Change the selector to `"ul h2, ul h3"`

Comment: @Alon - Hi the tabs in the accordion are being set to tabindex=0 when the page loads. When you activate a tab and it expands, the tabs are reset to tabindex=1. Is there a way that the tabindex value can always be 0? thx